# AngularJs Directive Issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api

```
   app.directive('ensureUnique', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, c) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {

$http.post("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Persons/CheckUserName", c.$modelValue).success(function (data) {
                    c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                }).error(function () {
                    c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Server:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public bool CheckUserName(string field)
        {
            bool IsUnique = false;
            if(field=="Meee")
            {
                IsUnique = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsUnique = true;
            }
            return IsUnique;
        }
```

I am trying to validate that the entered user is not already exists. I am using VS 2015. Okay my problem is i have a break-point in CheckUserName API.Its not hitting! When i try to access different API breakpoints are hitting as usual?

```
angular
       .module('app')
       .controller('Main', function ($scope, $http) {
           $scope.GetPersons = function () {
               $http.get("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Persons/GetPersons").success(function (data) {
                   $scope.Persons = data;
               }).error(function () {
                   alert("failed");
               });

           },
           $scope.PostPersons = function () {

               $http.post("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Persons/GetPersonsWithAge", $scope.Persons).success(function (data) {
                   $scope.PersonsWAges = data;
                   alert("Success");
               }).error(function () {
                   alert("failed");
               });

           }
       });
```

Note: These are two different projects but both are starting with debug.

Comment: Give your api url relative path: _"../api/Persons/GetPersonsWithAge"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying pass parameter to post method, you need to pass that in data `JSON` format, in the `$http.post` second parameter. That needs to be stringify as you are using .Net MVC.

**Code**

```
$http.post("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Persons/CheckUserName", JSON.stringify({
  field:  c.$modelValue
}))
```